# How to prevent browser closing just after launching in playwright (sync) python?

Tags: python, webautomation, playwright, playwright-python

I have placed launch browser
under **init** method of a **class A**

```
def __init__(self):
    browser = launch syntax
```

and another **method2** I have some operation to perform

I want to call method2 after initiating object for class A but *after* creating an Object of class browser is getting closed. How to stop closing the browser in sync mode??

Answer (score 0):

[A similar Question about this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65802677/how-to-keep-browser-opening-by-the-end-of-the-code-running-with-playwright-pytho/66121052#66121052)

Anyway, once the instance vanishes as well the browser does.
You need to make sure class A is still loaded, also from the code sample you posted it is quite hard to understand the problem, because it would be on the wider context.